# Antibodies combine with antigens in the presence or abscence of macrophages?

Tags: immunology

There was a mcq in book that antibodies combine with antigens when.... And the correct answer was if macrophages are absent. As far as I know macrophages release interleukin 1 which stimulates T helper cells to release interleukin 2 which further activates b cells. Plasma clone b cells then produce antibodies.  With respect to that macrophages presence is important.   Kindly clear my confusion.

Comment: Could you provide more complete context about what your book is saying?

Comment: It wasn't from the text.  It was just an mcq.

Comment: I suspect there is further context to the question that would help explain your confusion, without it I can't say much. If it's just completely isolated then I don't think it makes much sense as a MCQ by itself.